# .Net framework based software that loads Configuration file into microcontroller flash

Tags: c, embedded, .net-framework-version

I am new to microcontroller - Recently I am working on an embedded device that has a nice Software based on .Net framework. This Software allow users to change the pre-loaded configurations like TCP/IP parameters(IP,Port), temperature thresholds, timer setting, enabling and disabling specific peripherals or GPIO's. After we make our desired configuration there is a button on .Net Form titled as "Load Configuration" or "Save Configuration file" and when we press this button all configuration is loaded into embedded device serially.

Now i am interested in making the software like this which help me in just making some changes in configuration, instead of loading a huge hex file again and again. 
Please help me in this regard.

Comment: This takes more than just writing a .NET application. You also need to write an application that runs on the MCU that does the appropriate things based on what you send it from the computer. Start by continuing to learn about MCUs so that you have a better understanding of them, and dig into the details of how what you already have really works.